# delete space in string with recursive

Tags: python, function, recursion

I went to the exam 2-3 hours ago. Our teacher asked us to:

1) Take a string sentence from the user.

2) Send the string to a function.

3) Our task is to delete spaces but we can't use the string function and we must use recursion.

What's wrong?

```
def deletespace(name):
    if(len(name)==0):
        return ""
    else:
        str=""
        if(ord[name[0]])>chr(65) and ord(name[0])<chr(122):
            return str+deletespace(name[1:])

name=input("Please enter the name..")
deletespace(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `else` clause of your second `if` is missing. What do you return, in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The test might be over, but you may still be able to learn something from the following example:

```
>>> def del_char(text, char=' '):
    head, *tail = text
    return ('' if head == char else head) + \
           (del_char(tail, char) if tail else '')

>>> def main():
    name = input('Please enter your name: ')
    spaceless = del_char(name)
    print(spaceless)


>>> main()
Please enter your name: Arda Zaman
ArdaZaman
>>>
```

If you want an even more powerful version of the `del_char` function, try this `str_replace` function instead which can do the same thing as the first but has extended capabilities:

```
def str_replace(string, old=' ', new='', count=0):
    head, tail = string[0], string[1:]
    if head == old:
        head, count = new, count - 1
        if not count:
            return head + tail
    return head + str_replace(tail, old, new, count) if tail else head
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I see:

1). In line 6, you are trying to access the index of ord, `if(ord[name[0]])>chr(65) and ord(name[0])<chr(122):`, which throws a syntax error. What you probably meant is `if ord(name[0])>chr(65) and ord(name[0])<chr(122):`

2). The `else` case for the second `if` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are re-initializing your variables every time through the recursion.

2) You are never adding to your return value.

Try something more like:

```
def removespace(str):
    if len(str) == 0 : return ""
    if str[0] == " ":
        return removespace(str[1:])
    else :
        return str[0] + removespace(str[1:])
```

That should add each character to the return value in turn, skipping over any space character that it finds.

Answer (score 0):

```
def removewhite(string):

    if len(string) == 0:
        return ""
    if string[0] in " :/":
        return removewhite(string[1:])
    else:
        return string[0] + removewhite(string[1:])
string = "abcd , : def"
```

Comment: this will also remove ":" and "/" and add anything else you want in it

Answer (score 0):

you can also try something like this:

```
def remove_space(string, index = 0):
    if index < len(string):
        if string[index] == " ":
            string = string[:index] + string[index+1:]
        else:
            index +=1

        string = remove_space(string, index)
    return string

remove_space("what is your name")
```